# No space left on device, df shows 50%

Tags: linux, ntfs, storage, ntfs-3g

I have done everything I know about, and now I'm completely lost.
I'm getting an error on my Storage partition. The drive is a ntfs, and I'm using `ntfs-3g`, the disk is being shared between my Windows and my Linux partitions.
But I don't think that any of that should be an issue though.

I started off with the obvious `df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3       772G  434G  339G  57% /media/Storage
```

The partition that is of interest is `/dev/sda3` -- the partition labeled `Storage`.
It seems I'm only using 57%.

I then booted into my Windows partition and ran a `chkdsk e: /r` on the drive. It did find and correct some errors. However, it didn't fix the 'no space left on disk' error.

After some googling, I notice a lot of people with the same problem found a solution that deals with inodes, so I check that `df -ih`

```
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda3        340M  414K  339M    1% /media/Storage
```

Seems `/dev/sda3` is only using 1% of inodes, and according to @grawity. NTFS won't have problems with inodes since the space is dynamically allocated.

I ran a `dmesg`, but there doesn't seem to be anything obviously wrong, nothing that I can tell, but I'm not very familiar with the contents.
See the `dmesg` output at http://pastebin.com/jtrf8NB3

I was requested to look at `ntfs-3g --version` since apparently there used to be a bug where it would report 'no space left on device', but that was an older version.

```
ntfs-3g 2012.1.15AR.1 external FUSE 28
```

ntfs fragmentation does not seem to be the problem as it only had a 5% fragmentation. The partition was defragmented regardless.

As requested this is the output of a `mount` command:

```
/dev/sdb1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/sda2 on /media/Windows type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda3 on /media/Storage type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda5 on /media/Linux_partition type ext4 (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/golden/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=golden)
```

Comment: What is giving the no space on device error? Windows or Linux? If Linux, what Desktop Environment ae you using?

Comment: I'm not sure if such filesystems as NTFS ever run out of inodes – most of them dynamically allocate larger data structures when needed.

Comment: What version of NTFS-3G are you using?

Comment: @NikosC. NTFS-3g version ntfs-3g 2012.1.15AR.1 external FUSE 28

Comment: @terdon I was doing a git clone from my linux partition. Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: please provide output of bare `mount` command

Comment: Check your log files for more details.

Comment: At least FAT (DOS) did complain "No space on device" when the (root) directory got full.

Comment: Could this possibly have to do with NTFS5 sparse files, where Windows is seeing them as smaller than they are since they're sparse but ntfs-3g isn't doing it properly? Are any folders compressed in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click on the disk
2. Select the Quota tab
3. Turn it off.

Comment: Explain a bit of your diagnosis, and what the proposed solution does?

Comment: In my case it was already off, yet I can't write into last 42GB of 320GB drive..

Comment: Would NTFS-3G even enforce quota?

Comment: "Right-click on the disk" -- What does this mean?  What software or disk utility are you using here?

Answer (score 0):

Connect the disk to a Windows 7 machine and do chkdsk from CLI tool. Note that disk->Properties->Disk check is a different tool that does **not** solve the problem.